# XQuery : substring-before/after a specific char appearing many times?

Tags: xquery, xpath-2.0

I have this string ($str) : `67-89-90T`, and I want to keep `67-89`.

Of course `substring-before($str,'-')` returns `67`, but how can I choose the 2nd dash?

Comment: You might be interested in an alternative solution, that doesn't use RegExes.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Although, technically, tokenize also use a regex

Comment: @BeniBela, Yes, but for most uses of `tokenize()`, as this one, the second passed argument is "just a string" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A XPath 2 solution would be:

```
replace("67-89-90T", "(.*)-[^-]*$", "$1")
```

(also works, if there is no -, since then it does not match and replaces nothing)

Answer (score 1):

**An XPath 2.0 solution using tokenization -- might be more readable and understandable than using RegEx:**

```
string-join(tokenize(concat($vStr,'-'), '-')
                                     [.][not(position() eq last())], 
            '-')
```

**When run with an XQuery processor or with an XPath 2.0 processor, the expression:**

```
string-join(tokenize(concat('-', '67-89-90T','-'), '-')
                                     [.][not(position() eq last())], 
            '-')
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
67-89
```

Comment: You really call that *more* readable? But I'm disappointed, I expected you to post a XPath 1 solution...

Comment: @BeniBela, It is more readable than a RegEx -- because in this case the reader isn't supposed to know a whole new language -- RegEx. When formatted properly, it becomes even more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found `functx:substring-before-last`. Doesn't choose the specific dash but works for me in this case.

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_substring-before-last.html